To build a sync engine desktop application, cfapi and windows.storage.provider are important. In what scenario which should be used?
I am building a windows cloud sync engine application using cloud filter api. To start with the development, i am planned to register the Sync root using CfRegisterSyncRoot but the sample provided by the microsoft uses winrt::StorageProviderSyncRootInfo to register the Sync root. Are both common? How does both are common? Which way is correct?
Code using CfRegisterSyncRoot

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cfapi.h> // Include the Cloud Filter API header

LPCWSTR client_folder = L"C:\\Users\\<user_name>\\aa";
LPCWSTR server_folder = L"C:\\Users\\<user_name>\\ab";
#define STORAGE_PROVIDER_ID L"TestStorageProvider"
#define STORAGE_PROVIDER_ACCOUNT L"TestAccount1"

int main() {
 
    
    std::wstring syncRootIdentityStr(server_folder);
    syncRootIdentityStr.append(L"->");
    syncRootIdentityStr.append(client_folder);
    std::wcout << L"Sync root identity: " << syncRootIdentityStr << std::endl;
    LPCVOID syncRootIdentity = static_cast<LPCVOID>(syncRootIdentityStr.c_str());


   const CF_SYNC_REGISTRATION registration = { sizeof(CF_SYNC_REGISTRATION), L"MyProvider", L"1.0.0", syncRootIdentity ,sizeof(syncRootIdentity) , NULL, 0, {0} };
    const CF_SYNC_POLICIES policies = {
        sizeof(CF_SYNC_POLICIES),
        {CF_HYDRATION_POLICY_FULL, CF_HYDRATION_POLICY_MODIFIER_NONE},
        {CF_POPULATION_POLICY_FULL, CF_POPULATION_POLICY_MODIFIER_NONE},
        {CF_INSYNC_POLICY_TRACK_FILE_CREATION_TIME | CF_INSYNC_POLICY_TRACK_DIRECTORY_CREATION_TIME},
        CF_HARDLINK_POLICY_NONE,
        CF_PLACEHOLDER_MANAGEMENT_POLICY_DEFAULT };
    HRESULT hr = CfRegisterSyncRoot(client_folder, &registration, &policies, CF_REGISTER_FLAG_MARK_IN_SYNC_ON_ROOT);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        wprintf(L"Sync root registered successfully.\n");
        Sleep(30000);
    }
    else {

        wprintf(L"Error registering sync root. HRESULT: 0x%x\n", hr);
    }
    HRESULT hr1 = CfUnregisterSyncRoot(client_folder);

    return 0;
}



As far as I'm concerned, Winapi CfRegisterSyncRoot and Windows Runtime API winrt::StorageProviderSyncRoot* both are correct while there isn't enough document for Cloud Sync Engines.

Thanks for the response @YangXiaoPo-MSFT.
When i use the winrt::StorageProviderSyncRoot, the sync root appears in the navigation pane but while using the CfRegisterSyncRoot, the folder aa  gets grey X icon and unable to open that folder too. it does not appear in the navigation pane.
is this correct way of registering?

CfRegisterSyncRoot is only an NTFS API. StorageProviderSyncRootManager.Register adds Windows Shell (Explorer, etc.) "awareness" to it. So you must use it to enable related Windows Shell UI, or setup the registry manually (in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SyncRootManager)
